# Brackeys Fps Controller only moves camera up and down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

## The Problem

I am currently following Brackeys' First Person movement tutorial. However, I'm still stuck on the camera step as unlike most people having camera movement errors, I can only move my camera up and down (as opposed to only left and right).

### The Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouselook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 0f;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);


        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);

        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

(the script is stored in the camera. `playerBody` links to a cylinder mesh.)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);` you are resetting the `y` and `z` of the euler back to 0. I changed the update function to:

```
    void Update()
    {
       float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
       float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

       playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
       playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
```

And I got more expected behavior. I didn't watch the tutorial you are talking about so it may be fixed/explained further on.